# Android studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4 error adb cannot start

Tags: android, adb

I install Android studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4 and I have a problem: When I start Android Studio => I have a Notification: *daemon not running; starting now at tcp 5037 and virual machine loading device.
Please check Image: [*daemon not running; starting now at tcp 5037](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckcb2.png)

When check task manager => 2 adb now run. And I end task 1 adb => adb connect ok.
Please check Image: [2 adb now run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F1Zg.png)

I try reinstall, and uncheck Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging but not fix problem. Please help me fix problem :(( Thank you so much.

Sorry I'm not good English, hope everyone understands.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem:
Only Run as administrator in properites Android Studio => adb connect ok.Thank you so much! Please check my image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVD3w.png)